# Easy way to convert PC within network to image server?

Tags: networking, windows-7, web-server, url

Maybe the question is a little misleading, so here goes.

Without installing IIS or any other web server, is it possible to "host" images on a Windows 7 PC? Assuming my laptop in the network is called `FinanceLaptop`, it would basically be to "convert" that image on a remote folder in my laptop (ie. `\\FinanceLaptop\Image1.jpg`) to http://FinanceLaptop/Image1.jpg? This would only apply to our network.

The issue would be to keep the image in `FinanceLaptop`, not copy the image to another server and then get a URL pointing to this other server.

This would only apply to machines within our network.

The reason for this is that a PC in this network has wordpress installed. In our WP installation we can upload images, so if the image location is `\\FinanceLaptop\Image1.jpg` then we just see the link in the post. If we post `http://FinanceLaptop/Image1.jpg` we see a preview of the post.

So, let's say that I (FinanceLaptop) upload an image that doesn't follow the company's ethics code. I'm responsible for the image because it's in my machine.

Thanks.

Comment: IIS is available in any Windows system, including client ones. Just enable it and host anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see it in a web browser via the HTTP protocol, then you need to install an HTTP server (e.g. IIS). If you want to access the file to work with it, maybe in something like Word or Photoshop, then you would only need to turn on Windows file sharing.

Comment: should we be recommending IIS?

Comment: @chicks: For this purpose? Why not?

Comment: Back when I used Windows IIS was awful so I'd hesitate to encourage it.

Comment: The reason for doing this is so that everyone is responsible for the images posted in our wordpress installation. But if it's something that needs setup/configuration, chances are that it won't be approved.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of web server to host things via `http`.  It could be a short script, but usually apache or nginx is easier to get going for hosting a few static files.

Comment: Is it possible to install apache or nginx with just a script? For example, that I email the users in the group the script and they can then host images? It would need to be something that anyone can run.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to share a folder or a fiel within your network you can use the folder sharing option. [Here is a tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-essentials#1TC=windows-7) for windows 7.
For Linux look for `samba`

Comment: samba will not share things via http

Comment: Sorry i missd the last part of the question @chicks